# org.dbunit.database.AmbiguousTableNameException with MySQL 8

Tags: mysql, maven, plugins, dbunit, mojo

can anybody help me with this?

using dbunit-maven-plugin-1.0-beta-3 with mysql 8 to load meta data to database tables with mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.

Got the error as follows

```html
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Error executing database operation: CLEAN_INSERT
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:719)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error executing database operation: CLEAN_INSERT
    at org.codehaus.mojo.dbunit.OperationMojo.execute(OperationMojo.java:109)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: org.dbunit.database.AmbiguousTableNameException: USERTABLE
    at org.dbunit.dataset.OrderedTableNameMap.add(OrderedTableNameMap.java:198)
    at org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSet.initialize(DatabaseDataSet.java:227)
    at org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSet.getTableMetaData(DatabaseDataSet.java:275)
    at org.dbunit.operation.DeleteAllOperation.execute(DeleteAllOperation.java:109)
    at org.dbunit.operation.CompositeOperation.execute(CompositeOperation.java:79)
    at org.dbunit.ant.Operation.execute(Operation.java:195)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.dbunit.OperationMojo.execute(OperationMojo.java:100)
    ... 19 more
```

Btw, i have two databases with the same Table name.

FYI, it will work fine with mysql-connoctor-java-5.1.49. But in our case we need to use mysql connector 8.0.22.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the piece of pom dbunit configuration that makes this one fixed for me.

```html
<schema>test_database</schema>
<dataTypeFactoryName>org.dbunit.ext.mysql.MySqlDataTypeFactory</dataTypeFactoryName>                    
<metadataHandlerName>org.dbunit.ext.mysql.MySqlMetadataHandler</metadataHandlerName>
```

Comment: This fixed it for me in Spring Boot 3, DB Rider 1.35.0

Answer (score 0):

> Btw, i have two databases with the same Table name.

Does turning on [Qualified Table Names](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/properties.html#Qualified_Table_Names) feature fix the issue?  dbUnit may need to know which schema to use if the user has multiple.

For examples, there's one at the top of the feature page.  There's also a full example using [PrepAndExpectedTestCase](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/testcases/PrepAndExpectedTestCase.html#Configuration_Example_Using_Spring).

The general idea is:

```
final IDatabaseTester databaseTester = new xxxx();
final IDatabaseConnection dbUnitConnection = databaseTester.getConnection();
final DatabaseConfig databaseConfig = dbUnitConnection.getConfig();
config.setProperty(DatabaseConfig.FEATURE_QUALIFIED_TABLE_NAMES, true);
```

Comment: can you please give an example on how to configure  Qualified Table Names in maven project.

Comment: Did it fix your problem?

Comment: I have posted the answer that worked for me. Thanks for the answer @Jeff.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to the problem, in annotation format:

```
@DBUnit(schema = "test", qualifiedTableNames=true, dataTypeFactoryClass = MySqlDataTypeFactory.class, metaDataHandler= MySqlMetadataHandler.class )
```

You need to specify the schema and also dataTypeFactoryClass and metaDataHandler, if you have issues with MariaDB...